# django restframework channels send multiple socket messages at in one go

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-channels

I want to send an update message to the screen every time its details update. problem is frequent updates end up sending multiple messages to the screen. I want to wait 1 minute to watch for all the changes and send one message to the screen.

I am using the Django signal to watch for changes in the database. Here is my code.

```
//views.py

class ScreenWebListCreateView(PermissionOrganizationMixins, OrganizationQuerySetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ScreenWeb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScreenWebSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(organization=self.request.organization)

# retrieveupdatedestroyapiview
class ScreenWebRetrieveUpdateDestroyView(PermissionOrganizationMixins, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ScreenWeb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScreenWebSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(organization=self.request.organization)

//signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=ScreenWeb)
def send_socket_message_on_screen_web_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    send_update_message_socket_tv(instance.screenCodeApp)


@receiver(post_delete, sender=ScreenWeb)
def send_socket_message_on_screen_web_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    send_update_message_socket_tv(instance.screenCodeApp)
```

is there a way to wait for some time to include all changes and then send an update message?